# Python splitting data correctly

Tags: python, split

So I have to split my data from a csv file.(Haven't worked with python a lot.)

The code I'm using is:

```
data = open('C:\DATA\data.csv','r')
rdata=[]
lines_data=data.readlines()
col_number = 30
for s in range(col_number):
    for x in lines_data:
        rdata.append(x.split(',')[s])
data.close()
print(rdata)
```

The result I'm getting is one single list that contains all numbers, but I wanna get 31. What should I do?
*I am not supposed to use any libraries

**edit**
the data set I'm using can be found here [https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+(Diagnostic)]

the output data is something like this :

```
['17.99', '20.57', '19.69', '11.42',........'0.124', '0.07039']
```

which is a list with many numbers but as I mentioned before I want to get a list that contains 31 columns.Thank you in advance :)

Comment: paste your input data.csv

Comment: Can you share the sample CSV data here and desired output?

Comment: This is clearly XY problem. Instead of trying to fix this ill-approach, check how to read csv file in python properly

Answer (score -1):

First of all, rolling your own CSV reader is generally a bad idea – it is surprisingly hard to get it right! Use the `csv` module from the standard library. However, since you seem to be in a classroom situation, maybe you have to.

The reason that you are getting all numbers in a single list is that you are creating a single list and appending each number to it!

I looks like you want 31 lists, one for each column. The obvious way to do this would be to create a list of 31 empty lists, then iterate over the input file and, for each row, iterate over the columns and append the value from the column to the corresponding list.

Answer (score -2):

In actual python, you'd read a simple csv file like this:

```
with open(r'C:\DATA\data.csv') as fp:
    rdata = [line.split(',') for line in fp]
```

Comment: what if there are commas, inside a field, properly quoted? You are just guessing without knowing the input file

Comment: @buran: ^^^ a _simple_ csv file. For "what if" cases, `import csv`

Comment: That's why I marked as dupe and clear XY problem. You should have done the same. _simple csv file_ does not exclude quoted sep in the field